# PHPStorm generate phpdoc

Tags: phpstorm, silex

I have method like this:

```
    public function connect (Application $app)
    {

    $controller = $app['controllers_factory'];

    $controller->get('/login', function () {
       return 'test';
    });

    return $controller;
    }
```

Everything works fine, but I would like to save $app in private field, like this

```
    private $app;

    public function connect (Application $app)
    {

    $this->app = $app;

    $controller = $this->app['controllers_factory'];

    $controller->get('/login', function () {
       return 'test';
    });

    return $controller;
    }
```

In this case PHPStrom throws error "method get not found in class". I tried phpdoc but it didn't work (As you see i use SILEX micro-framework)

Comment: Perhaps use constructor, set your $app (private) variable there and whole class has access to it. And what does PHPdoc with it?

Comment: With constructor everything works fine (method is now found) but Silex doesn't let me to use constructor.

Comment: I am not sure what you try to accomplish, please edit question and add whole code of that file. Or try to call parent constructor in your constructor.

Comment: Oh dear i forget add param while creating new instance ;) Now everything is fine!

Comment: A bit off-topic: But why do you set it as a property, as you only need it in the `connect` method?

Comment: Because I want to extend basic class with new methods ;) This is piece of code

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete gets stuck at this step, because it's unclear whats the value coming from array (even if it's an object that acts like an array).

```
$controller = $this->app['controllers_factory'];
```

There are two possibilities. First, if you have an array that consist of elements that share a single type, you can specify the type like this:

```
/**
 * @var Application[]
 */
private $app;
```

An alternate method is to specify the type of a variable inline:

```
/** @var Application $controller */
$controller = $this->app['controllers_factory'];
```

Both options are supported by PHPStorm.